# Cloudera to HDP SOLR(version 5.5.2) Data Migration | Failed to Update solr indexes after restoration on solr cloud

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, restore, hortonworks-data-platform, solrcloud

SOLR version - 5.5.2

My Project requirement is to transfer solr cloud indexes from cloudera cluster to HDP cluster.

- Data is huge(1 billion indexed records on production), hence re-indexing is not an option.

We have tried solr restore and backup APIs but data is not visible on cloud. Please check if we are missing any step from below ==>

1) **Allowed snapshot** (Cloudera cluster) :
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -allowSnapshot /user/solr/CollectionName

2) **Created snapshot** :
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfs -createSnapshot /user/solr/CollectionName/

3) **Created solr collection on HDP cluster** : with same name, same number of shards and replicas.

4) **Used “distcp” to transfer snapshot** :
sudo -u solr hadoop distcp hdfs://NameNodeCDH-IP:8020/user/solr/CDHCollectionName/.snapshot/s20180601-131020.000  hdfs://NameNodeHDP-IP:8020/user/solr

5) **Restore snapshot on collection level** :
sudo -u solr hadoop fs -cp /user/solr/s20180601-131020.000/* /user/solr/HDPCollectionName/
Restored snapshot from /user/solr to collection directory for each shard and replica.

**OUTCOME** : HDFS directory restored but DATA not visible on SOLR UI. 0 records displayed. Checked HDFS directory using-
sudo hadoop fs -du -s -h /user/solr/HDPCollectionName/

[HDP SOLR Data directory size -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi4gR.png)

[SOLR CLOUD DATA SIZE - ZERO 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12qhC.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue recently. The problem was because of restore status that was in progress state so follow below steps.


1. curl 'http://SolrHostName:8983/solr/CollectionName_shardNo_ReplicaNO/replication?command=restore&name=snapshotName&location=SolrCollectionDirectory' 


2. curl 'http://SolrHostName:8983/solr/CollectionName_shardNo_ReplicaNO/replication?command=restorestatus'

Once found restorestatus successfully then data will be visible on SOLR UI.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, This resolved my issue and data is visible after restore status is successful.